# "order lost" in X-Cart in return section of payment module

Tags: x-cart

I wrote a payment module for X-Cart.
My return url section is:

```
require './auth.php';

if (!func_is_active_payment('cc_mellat.php'))
    exit;

$rescode=$_POST['ResCode'];
$RefID=$_POST['RefId'];
$saleOrderId=$_POST['saleOrderId'];
$SaleReferenceId=$_POST['SaleReferenceId'];

$tmp = func_query_first("SELECT sessionid,param1 FROM $sql_tbl[cc_pp3_data] WHERE ref='".$saleOrderId."'");
$bill_output['sessid'] = $tmp['sessionid'];

$bill_output['billmes']="RefId:".$RefId." - ResCode: ".$rescode." - SaleReferenceId:".$SaleReferenceId;
// Approved
if ($rescode == 0 && $is_md5) {
    $bill_output['code'] = 1;       
// Declined
} else {
    echo "Error: ".$rescode;
    $bill_output['code'] = 2;       
}
var_dump($bill_output); 

require($xcart_dir.'/payment/payment_ccend.php');
```

but after payment X-Cart says:

```
Order declined.
Review your data or contact the store administrator.

Reason: Error: Your order was lost
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you use undefined variable $is_md5 here:

```
if ($rescode == 0 && $is_md5) {
```

Answer (score 1):

See my post [here](http://forum.x-cart.com/showthread.php?t=64498). It fails due to a SQL error because the name of the `xcart_cc_pp3_data` field is `sessid` *not* `sessionid`.

Switch to the correct field name, and your order will be found. (I had the same `order not found` error until I found & fixed the SQL.)